# How to record with an ingame camera and play it back in reverse (UNITY3D)

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, playback

I am making a 3d fps game using the Unity Game Engine. One of the functions I want to have is that when you die, the entirety of the level is played in reverse and fast-motion. Is there a way to do this using a second camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about the Command Design Pattern!  That should help getting you think about a strategy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say that to you. But you can't do that simply.
Unity have a TimeScale that you can tune (slow down or speed up). The "Zero" TimeScale corresponding to the game paused because nothing moves :

```
void PauseGame ()
{
    Time.timeScale = 0;
}
```

You will have to manually record every scene movements and run them back when you need to make to rewind. You can look here to make a [first step](https://answers.unity.com/questions/782409/how-to-recordsave-and-replayload-a-players-movemen.html?_ga=2.249329671.149619711.1596366401-1197247844.1596366401)